# How do I add text from an array to a label

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a very simple app as I am new to swift. I am trying to make an app where there are four textfields, someone can put in words in each of the text fields and it picks one of them at random. However I am getting the error: 'Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String?'.

[image]

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: When people ask you to share your code, they *do not* mean that you should post an image of your code. They mean that you should copy and paste the actual text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Leif answered, "(\randomIndex)" will let you print the index you generated.  If you want to print the actual text for the text field though...

```
let randomTextField = array[randomIndex]
label.text = randomTextField.text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(4)
label.text = "\(yourArrayOfStrings[randomIndex])"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either put the Int value as "\(index)" or String(index)